# GCC4.2 build warning : Default deployment version is greater than the max value for the iPhone simulator 3.1.2 SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcodebuild

I upgraded an iPhone project from the 2.2.1 SDK to 3.0 SDK recently...

And when I build the project I am getting the following warning:

```
GCC 4.2 default deployment target 10.6.2 for architecture 'i386' and 
variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value 10.6 for the 
Simulator - iPhone OS 3.1.2 SDK
```

I have the iPhone OS Deployment target set to iPhone OS 3.0

Any idea what could be causing this 'warning' to show up.

Regards
- SY

Answer (score 1):

Experienced a similar problem when building with iOS4.0 on Snow Leopard:

"GCC 4.2 default deployment target 10.6.3 for architecture 'i386' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value 10.6 for the Simulator - iPhone OS 4.0 SDK."

Not sure of all the implications, but here's what made it go away:

In xCode:
Project (menu)
Edit Project Settings (menu item)
Build (tab)
Deployment (section)

Change the value of "Mac OS X Deployment Target"
from "Compiler Default" to "Mac OS X 10.6"

Answer (score 0):

try going to the appropriate directory:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/lib/
```

then as su:

```
cp crt1.10.5.o crt1.10.6.o
```

That seemed to fix it for me.